# How to reorder file in chronological order

Tags: r

I have a dataset with multiple columns but I'd like to change the order in chronological order by date!

This is a really bad example but would there be a code to r

| Station | year | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020 | D |
| 2 | 2019 | C |
| 3 | 2017 | A |
| 4 | 2018 | B |

This is a really bad example but would there be a code to reorder by date oldest to newest?

| Station | year | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2017 | A |
| 4 | 2018 | B |
| 2 | 2019 | C |
| 1 | 2020 | D |

To look something like this!

Any help would be amazing! :)
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well... "2020" is not a date, and you can order the column as regular integer.

But, if you had dates like "2020-01-25"... transforming strings to dates is easy as...

```
df <- tibble(n = c(1,2,3,4),
             dt = c("2020-01-01","2019-01-01","2017-01-01", "2018-01-01"),
             l = c("D","C","A","B"))

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    dt = as.Date(dt)
  ) %>% 
  arrange(
    dt
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `ymd ()` function from `lubridate` package to bring `dt` to date format and `year ()` to extract the year. With this format you can sort your dates with `arrange`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
# data borrowed from abreums
df <- tibble(n = c(1,2,3,4),
             dt = c("2020-01-01","2019-01-01","2017-01-01", "2018-01-01"),
             l = c("D","C","A","B"))

df1 <- df %>% 
  mutate(dt = ymd(dt),           # "2020-01-01"
         dt = year(dt)) %>%      # "2020"
  arrange(dt)
```

[image]